# list tags contained by a branch

Tags: git

How can I list tags contained by a given branch, the opposite of:

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```

Which "only list tags which contain the specified commit".

If something like this does not exist, how do I test whether a commit is contained by another commit so that I can script this?

I could do this:

```
commit=$(git rev-parse $branch)
for tag in $(git tag)
do
    git log --pretty=%H $tag | grep -q -E "^$commit$"
done
```

But I hope there is a better way as this might take a long time in a repository with many tags and commits.

Comment: See [this answer to this duplicate post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10603278/11343) for another nice way to do it

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
git tag --merged <branch>
```

From the man page:

```
--[no-]merged <commit>

Only list tags whose tips are reachable, or not reachable if --no-merged is used, from the specified commit (HEAD if not specified).
```

I believe this option was added quite recently - it definitely wasn't available back when the original question was posed and the above answers suggested.  Since this thread is still the first hit in Google for the question I figured I'd throw it in for anyone who scrolls down to the bottom looking for an answer that involves less typing than the accepted answer (and for my own reference when I forget this answer again next week).

Comment: Was added on Sept 2015, [it seems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32991687/777285). Should now be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: agreed, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: listing tags in a branch but not another is also possible: `git tag --merged debian --no-merged upstream` (useful when one branch is merged in the other)

Comment: @FranklinPiat: "error: option `no-merged' is incompatible with --merged"

Comment: @FranklinPiat - I thought that worked too, but according to this bug report it was actually discarding the first option entirely: https://github.com/git/git/commit/17d6c744dc0d5ed4cd0f228da14239ea2654f05b

Comment: Short, understandable and exact answer. Thank you @JamHandy !

Answer (score 47):

This might be close to what you want:

```
git log --simplify-by-decoration --decorate --pretty=oneline "$committish" | fgrep 'tag: '
```

But, the more common situation is to just find the most recent tag:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 "$committish"
```

- `--tags` will search against lightweight tags, do not use it if you only want to consider annotated tags.
- Do not use `--abbrev=0` if you want to also see the usual “number of ‘commits on top’ and abbreviated hash” suffix (e.g. v1.7.0-17-g7e5eb8).

Comment: As of Git 1.7.10 it doesn't work  `--pretty=format:%d ` lists refs without saying whether it's a tag or a branch

Comment: @CharlesB: Edited to change to `log`. I have not properly bisected it, but it looks like the change (regression?) may have happened back in 1.7.2: [a7524128](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7524128750ebf34fe0639e1e5d7abd03aff0302) changed the internal decoration text, but only adjusted one of the formatting functions to compensate (log-tree.c:show_decoration was adjusted, while pretty.c:format_decoration got hit with the (unintended?) change).

Comment: For me this gives: fatal: ambiguous argument '': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions (git version 1.7.9.5)

Comment: @rooby: That error message indicates that you included an empty string somewhere in your command. Did you substitute the hash string of the commit/branch/tag that that you are investigating (i.e. where I used the placeholder `$committish`)?

Comment: Ah oops. Although I don't really see why you want a commit hash in there if you are concerned with a branch not a commit. If I omit the "$committish" part all together I get the results I would expect.

Comment: @rooby a branch name is a valid committish; using “committish” as the placeholder indicates that any commit identifier is acceptable (see [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)). Omitting it entirely defaults to HEAD.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question it just shows the most recent tag... not the "tags" (plural) "contained by a branch"

Answer (score 14):

to list all tags reachable on the current branch:

```
git log --decorate=full --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=oneline HEAD | \
sed -r -e 's#^[^\(]*\(([^\)]*)\).*$#\1#' \
       -e 's#,#\n#g' | \
grep 'tag:' | \
sed -r -e 's#[[:space:]]*tag:[[:space:]]*##'
```

Comment: Replace `sed -r` by `sed -E`  on OS X.

Comment: Format of `git log --decorate=full --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=oneline HEAD` has changed a bit since this answer was redacted

Comment: `git log --decorate --oneline | egrep '^[0-9a-f]+ \(tag: ' | sed -r 's/^.+tag: ([^ ]+)[,\)].+$/\1/g'`

Comment: shkschneider's comment doesn't include a tag if it's on the latest commit.

Answer (score 7):

I do not have enough reputation to comment on other people's posts, but this is in response to the answer and its comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698213/2598329. In order to show all of the tags reachable by the current branch, including the tag on the HEAD commit, you can use the following:

```
git log --decorate --oneline | egrep '^[0-9a-f]+ \((HEAD, )?tag: ' | ssed -r 's/^.+tag: ([^ ]+)[,\)].+$/\1/g'
```

One caveat - I use super sed, so you may need to change my "ssed" to sed.

And for the hell of it, here it is in PowerShell:

```
git log --decorate --oneline | % { if ($_ -match "^[0-9a-f]+ \((HEAD, )?tag: ") { echo $_} } | % { $_ -replace "^.+tag: ([^ ]+)[,\)].+$", "`$1" }
```

-- 
-a

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just change your answer to use sed instead of ssed seeing as that will more likely be what other users have?

Comment: i agree, but it should be noted that on os x the default sed doesn't have the `-r` option. need to switch to `gnu-sed` via homebrew... or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

all answer only list tags, but if you want them in chronological order, you need to add `--sort=taggerdate`

or example:

```
 git tag --merged release/11.x --sort=taggerdate
studio-1.4
llvmorg-10-init
llvmorg-11-init
llvmorg-11.0.0-rc1
llvmorg-11.0.0-rc2
llvmorg-11.0.0-rc3
llvmorg-11.0.0-rc4
llvmorg-11.0.0-rc5
llvmorg-11.0.0-rc6
llvmorg-11.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

**Windows-specific answer for anyone looking.**

(*Powershell has recently gone open-source & cross-platform so command given below will run on the systems other than Windows too.*)

> NOTE: below is for old versions of git or for specific use cases!

*For powershell:*

```sh
git log --simplify-by-decoration --decorate --pretty=oneline "$committish" | Select-String 'tag: '
```

you can also use: `-CaseSensitive` flag for Select-String to make it case sensitive

*For cmd:*

```sh
git log --simplify-by-decoration --decorate --pretty=oneline | findstr -i "tag: "
```

you can remove `-i` to make the search case sensitive

> NOTE: For newer versions & cross-platform, cross-terminal as long as it supports git command:

```sh
git tag --merged <branchname>
```

you can use options like format, color, sort & many others with this. Check it all out here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
# get tags on the last 100 commits:
base_rev=master~100
end_rev=master
for rev in $(git rev-list $base_rev..$end_rev)
do 
    git describe --exact-match $rev 2> /dev/null
done
```

Comment: This only works if your repo has >100 commits and if the tag you need is >100 commits ago, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I list annotated tags matching a pattern (TAG_PREFIX*) in reverse chronological order. This recipe uses git-describe.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tag=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --match TAG_PREFIX*)
until [ -z $tag ]; do
    echo $tag
    tag=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --match TAG_PREFIX* $tag^ 2>/dev/null);
done
```

This won't work if multiple tags matching the pattern point to the same commit. For that, here is another recipe that uses git-rev-list and git-tag to list all tags, matching TAG_PREFIX*, starting from a commit (HEAD in this example).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git rev-list HEAD | while read sha1; do
    tags=( "$(git tag -l --points-at $sha1 TAG_PREFIX*)" )
    [[ ! -z ${tags[*]} ]] && echo "${tags[@]}" | sort -r
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `git branch --contains` (Git since 1.5.7, at least)

Comment: this doesn't even remotely do what's asked. "With --contains, shows only the branches that contain the named commit " ... he didn't ask for branches containing a commit. He asked for tags in a branch.

Comment: indeed, doesn't answer the OP at all, but very useful for a common case: check if a tag is present on the branch (e.g. don't deploy if not on main)

`[[ $(git branch --contains $(git rev-parse $TAG)) =~ '\bmaster|main$' ]]; echo $?`

Answer (score 0):

Efficient for large numbers of tags and gets easy format flexibility:

```
{ git rev-list --first-parent ${1:-HEAD}
  git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(objecttype)  %(refname)
                             %(*objectname) *(%(objecttype)) %(refname)' 
} \
| awk '
  NF==1   { revs[$1]=1; next }
          { if ( $1 in revs ) print $1,$2,$3 }
'
```

which gets all refs, add `refs/tags` to the f-e-r to restrict it.

Answer (score -1):

[git describe](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) (or some variant of it) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: No, `git describe` will only list one tag/ref.