# Is it possible with Git to retrieve a list of tags that exist only in a certain branch?

Tags: git, tags, branch

I would like to know if it's possible in Git to retrieve a list of tags (much like the result of the `git tag` command), but the list should be limited only to a certain branch.

If this is possible, can anyone explain how this is done? Perhaps with some pattern-matching magic?

Comment: I may be wrong but it requires (little) scripting

Comment: Not sure but is this what you want? [list tags contained by a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2381665/11343)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach would be possible with the new git tag options `--merged` (in git 2.7+, Q4 2015)

```
git tag --merged <abranchname>
```

See [commit 5242860](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5242860f548d1869ac2779726ad496f0ae8ab5ca), ... (10 Sept 2015) by [Karthik Nayak (`KarthikNayak`)](https://github.com/KarthikNayak).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8a54523](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a54523f0f70134327e7b2a625b1777c796b07d5), 05 Oct 2015)</sup>

tag.c: implement '--merged' and '--no-merged' options

> Use '`ref-filter`' APIs to implement the '`--merged`' and '`--no-merged`' options into '`tag.c`'.
>
> - The '`--merged`' option lets the user to only list tags merged into the named commit.
> - The '`--no-merged`' option lets the user to only list tags not merged into the named commit.
>
> If no object is provided it assumes `HEAD` as the object.

Comment: This is okay, but it does not show tags in creation order, which can be an issue when multiple branches are tagged and merged.

Comment: @ingyhere Then you would need to add a sort order option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919313/6309: `git tag --sort=-creatordate `

Answer (score 6):

I think this will do what you want:

```
 git log --pretty='%H' <branch> |
   xargs -n1 git describe --tags --exact-match 2>/dev/null
```

This uses `git log` to get a list of commits in a branch, and then passes them to `git describe` to see if they correspond to a tag.

Comment: +1, best way. can be made really faster by adding `--simplify-by-decoration` to `git log`, it gives only commits that match a refspec so you don't loop over *all* commits

Comment: Hey, i am also looking for a solution similar to this :
I just posted a question on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316306/listing-the-tags-in-git-from-a-specific-branch) and then happened to read your question

Comment: @iDev: Did you try the solution of larsks? Did this work out for you?