# git branch flag for --no-merged and not --contains?

Tags: git, git-branch

`git branch --contains master` returns the names of branches from whose tips `master` is reachable.

`git branch --merged master` returns the names of branches whose tips are reachable from `master`.

`git branch --no-merged master` returns the names of branches whose tips aren't reachable from `master`.

What is the flag (perhaps in a newer version of `git`?) to show the names of branches whose tips are neither reachable from `master`, nor can reach `master` in their own ancestry?  In other words, what flag gives the effect of `--no-merged --no-contains`?

To put it another way, how to show branches which could not have a fast forward merge into master nor have a fast forward merge from master into them?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, not necessarily at all.  Try `git checkout -b divergent_branch master~3`, then make a commit, then `git log --online --graph master divergent_branch`.  `master` itself is just a movable pointer to a commit; just because a branch shares history in common with master doesn't mean that branch fully includes *or* is included in `master`'s history.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen also see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/5419599)  When I say one branch "includes another" I mean the DAG of history reachable from the branch pointer includes the full DAG of history reachable from the other branch pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update April 2017**, as I mentioned in "[How to list all git branches containing a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32988289/6309)", the option `--no-contains` is [now supported with Git 2.13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1d3d46146e1256efe8ad2a2bb0dd877a738c07d).

**Original Answer**

> What is the flag (perhaps in a newer version of git?)

First, the `--(no-)merged` flags you mention have been generalized as ref-filter [fairly recently (git 2.7, Sept. 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991687/6309).

> `--no-contains`

A quick search reveals this option does not exist (in any of the branches of the git repo:

```
MINGW64 ~/git/git (master)
$ git branch -a | tr -d \*|grep -v origin|xargs git grep --break --heading --line-number 'no\-contain'
```

So you would need to script that, listing all branches which are not selected by `--contains` (but are listed in `--no-merged`).

> "`git tag/branch/for-each-ref`" family of commands long allowed to
>   filter the refs by:
>
> - "`--contains X`" (show only the refs that are
>     descendants of `X`),
> - "`--merged X`" (show only the refs that are
>     ancestors of `X`),
> - "`--no-merged X`" (show only the refs that are not
>     ancestors of `X`).
>
> One curious omission, "`--no-contains X`" (show only the refs that are not descendants of `X`) has been added to them.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think `--no-contains` was a real option; I thought it would convey in simple fashion what I meant.  I'm not sure I quite get the significance of `ref-filter`.  Is that a new `git` command in 2.7?  E.g. `git ref-filter (something)`?

Comment: @Wildcard no, ref-filter refers to https://github.com/git/git/blob/8a54523f0f70134327e7b2a625b1777c796b07d5/ref-filter.h#L82-L87: "API for filtering a set of refs. Based on the type of refs the user has requested, we iterate through those refs and apply filters as per the given ref_filter structure and finally store the filtered refs in the ref_array structure".

Comment: Ah, okay.  I'm not up on C code yet (hasn't been in my line of territory) so I only get the general idea.  If I'm understanding you correctly it seems like this is just an implementation detail that has changed, and `git branch (--merged | --no-merged | --contains)` will still work just the same in 2.7?

Comment: @Wildcard yes, that set of options if available to git branch only for git 2.7+

Comment: Now I'm confused.  Git 1.7.12.4 works correctly with all three options specified in my last comment.  What options are you referring to that are only available in 2.7+?

Comment: @Wildcard you are right. I mixed it up with `git tag`. The ref-filter was more an internal refactoring which allowed to propose those same options (initially avaible in git branch) to other commands like `git-tag` and `git for-each-ref` (hence the importance of using the ref-filter API). But the answer stands: no '`--no-merged`', and a need for a script.