# Listing the tags in git from a specific branch

Tags: git, tags, repository

I have used repo sync to a repository (from head) and have passed a branch named (mybranch). I got a list of tags in git by using:

```
git tag -l
```

Then with the help of a regular expression I obtained the tags which match a specific pattern.

Is it possible to get the branch name of those shortlisted tags and then select only the tags only from a particular branch?

I saw 
    git branch -r 
command but can it be used along with the tag name as well?

Comment: Do you find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381665/list-tags-contained-by-a-branch)

Comment: No I want to filter the tags based on the branch name

Comment: What do you call the "branch name" of a tag ?

Comment: Probably the tags which point to commits referred by a branch are sought. A tag can thus belong to more than one branch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the branches which refer to a commit referred by a tag:

```
git branch --contains <tagname>
```

Just repeat the command for each tag you are looking the branch(es) of:

```
git tag -l 'example*' |xargs -n1 git branch --contains
```

Be aware, that tags can refer to any object, not only commits, but the 'branch' command expects commits only.

Comment: When I execute the command 
    git branch -r
I get a list of all branches but I want a to select a particular branch only and select the tags which belong to that branch

Comment: `git tag -l 'example*' |while read tag; do git branch -a --contains "$tag" |grep 'that-branch' >/dev/null && echo "$tag"; done`

Comment: It is very slow and ineffective, though

Comment: Faster: `git tag -l |while read tag; do test $(git rev-list -n1 ^that-branch "$tag" |wc -l) = 0 && echo $tag; done`

Comment: My fastest: `git log --format='%d' that-branch |grep '^.'`
That has a problem of listing the branch names which also belong to that-branch (graph-wise). And the tag names are enclosed in brackets.

Comment: Improve selection a little: `git log --format='%d' --decorate=full that-branch |grep 'refs/tags'`
Still has a problem of listing the branch names if they are at a commit already referenced by a tag.

Comment: I have synced a repo to my workspace from head. I want to know the tag in question was created on which branch. (While syncing it i used a branch -b mybranch) but I want to know it was originally on which branch

Comment: That is the same as saying: I want to know which branches contain the given tag