# How to list all tags within a certain git branch

Tags: git

I have a couple of branches in my git repo. I would like to know if there is a command that lists all the tags within a certain branch not all the tags in the whole repo.

I tried  `git tag --contains`. but it didn't work as expected.

Image 1, there's a list of all the tags with their hashes (the marked two tags have the same hash/commit)
[image]
Image 2, as you can see I'm on a branch called "b" [image]
Image 3, I queried which branch contains the hash of both tags (both have same hash) and it said they are on branch "b" (the one I'm currently on)[image]

Image 4, describing the branch tags, It only gave me ONE tag[image]

Image 5, also describing the tags of the hash that is supposed to point to the commit that is tagged with both tags, it only shows ONE tag again[image]

Comment: Isn't that the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/2381665/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/10603278/6309?

Comment: what I had in mind was a simple command to list all the tags within a branch, not a combination of commands. Maybe git does not index the tags by branches. I don't know that's why I asked :D.

Comment: Tags point to commits, and the same commits can exist in multiple branches. Thus it can not directly tell the tags in your branch, because it would need to compare all tags with all commits in your current branch and see which tags point to contained commits.

Comment: I just updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: @CoDEmanX So is it just like I said? git has no way of indexing the tags across the branches?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by indexing, but it simply does not store a reverse lookup table - although it technically could. But it's commonly not needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381665/list-tags-contained-by-a-branch does the trick if I use `--pretty=%d` and replace  "$committish" by the name of the branch (e.g. devel), and it's fast. I came up with another solution, but it's very slow: http://pastebin.com/K5CFtYWb

Comment: @CoDEmanX Yes I meant that there is no lookup table that maps maps tags -> branches. Did you take a look at the images that I posted? Is that normal? or do you have an explanation for it?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's possible that multiple tags got the same hash. If I create 3 tags with no other action inbetween, 2 at HEAD (branch devel) and the 3rd for branch master, then all 3 show different hashes when I `show-ref --tags`?!

Comment: What if you `git describe --all HASH`? Or how many results does `git rev-list --tags | grep HASH` yield?

Comment: @CoDEmanX It gave me only the tag from the last image!

Comment: So, if I create a tag for a particular commit, the hashes will be identical. And like you said, they aren't listed, only one is returned. This works for me however: `git for-each-ref refs/tags | grep HASH`.

Comment: @CoDEmanX Thanks man! ALOT! :D .... I believe I have a theory.
The hash commit that I provided is tagged with more than one tag as I stated. The command "git describe --tags" returns only the last tag. When I used the command that you provided "git for-each-ref refs/tags | grep $HASH", it returned both tags for the hash as I expected.

please post your previous comment as an answer to my question :)

Comment: I would, but the question was closed :( You would need to open another,  so I could post my answer. If you do so, rollback this question to your initial question. BTW: I mailed to the git mailing list about this and asked for `git tag --list --branch ...` and that `for-each-ref` combined with `grep` is apparently the only way to retrieve all tag names.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I already flagged a moderator to reopen the question and will let you know, because I didn't find any of these info at the referred question. Also, it's pretty lame to have to add for-each in order to get the tags for a certain commits and misleading as well! the git describe --tags should support all tags by default. Thanks, man alot again! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list tags contained by a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381665/list-tags-contained-by-a-branch)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To print all tags, that point to a certain commit, you can do:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags | grep HASH
```

Or if you are on Windows and don't use Cygwin or similar:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags | find "HASH"
```

If you want the tag name only, you can't use Git's `--format` , because we need it for grep'ing. Thus we need to strip the stuff we aren't interested in away in the final step (Linux/Cygwin):

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags | grep HASH | sed -r "s/.*refs\/tags\/(.*)/\1/"
```

Regarding the initial question:

This iterates over all tags in all branches, asks git which branches contain each tag and filters based on the supplied branch name - but be warned, it's **super slow**:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags --format "%(refname)" | while read x
do
    if git branch --contains $x | grep -q "^[ *] master$"
        then echo $x
    fi
done
```

The following [taken from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381665/list-tags-contained-by-a-branch) is much faster:

```
git log --simplify-by-decoration --decorate --pretty=oneline "master" | fgrep 'tag: '
```

... but if multiple tags point to the same commit, it will produce:

```
 (HEAD, tag: Test-Tag1, tag: Test-Tag2, Test-Tag3, fork/devel, devel)
 (tag: Another-Tag)
 (tag: And-Another)
```

(three tags `Test-Tag*` pointing to the same commit)

I wrote a Python script that outputs tag names only, one per line (tested on Windows only):

```
import os
from subprocess import call

print("-" * 80)

dirpath = r"D:\Projekte\arangodb" # << Put your repo root path here!

tagdir = os.path.join(dirpath, ".git", "refs", "tags")
commitspath = os.path.join(dirpath, "_commit_list.tmp")

# could probably read from stdin directly somewhow instead of writing to file...
# write commits in local master branch to file
os.chdir(dirpath)
os.system("git rev-list refs/heads/master > " + commitspath)

tags = {}
for tagfile in os.listdir(tagdir):
    with open(os.path.join(tagdir, tagfile), "r") as file:
        tags[file.read().strip()] = tagfile

tags_set = set(tags)

commits = {}
with open(commitspath, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        commits[line.strip()] = 1
os.remove(commitspath)

commits_set = set(commits)

for commit in sorted(commits_set.intersection(tags_set), key=lambda x: tags[x]):
    print(tags[commit])
```

Result:

```
Test-Tag1
Test-Tag2
Test-Tag3
Another-Tag
And-Another
```

The commit hash could optionally be printed too for every tag, simply modify the last line to `print(commit, tags[commit])`. The script seems to perform very well by the way!

Ideally, git would support something like the following command to avoid all these workarounds:

```
git tag --list --branch master
```

Comment: Excellent reference summary, man....Thanks a million and your effort is much appreciated :)

Comment: You can read the mailing discussion I started on the following page: http://marc.info/?t=144034385100002&r=1&w=2

Comment: I'm working on 'git tag --merged', that would be the easiest way to go about this :)

Comment: @KarthikNayak I hope you understood me and CoDEmanX correctly. Our goal is to list any tag in a given branch. So If you were to implement any command it should take a branch name as an input sth like that "git tag --merged -b branch_name" :)

Comment: @KarthikNayak: Sounds great! I hope it will return tags for a certain branch, even if the commits the tags point to were not actually merged (i.e. tags created in same branch, pointing to commits committed to that very same branch). Any idea when to expect this feature?

Comment: I was just reading your post on the list, that'd exactly what its meant to do, the syntax will be like "git tag --merged=<branch_name>" of sorts. It still needs to be accepted but you can check out the patch series on the list :)

Comment: I wished it was hosted on Github or somewhere else but the mailing list - looks like hours of work to me for someone who wants to build git/next with your patches applied. All available thumbs up for your patches to land soon! BTW: Jeff King pointed out that a better name would be `--contained-in`. What is your opinion on that? Sounds clearer to me than `--merged`, and it's shorter than `--go-all-the-way-down-from-specified-commit-or-branch-tip-to-the-root-and-return-tags-that-point-to-a-commit-we-saw-during-our-traversal`. Maybe this would work too: `--from-root-to HERE`

Comment: There ya go https://github.com/KarthikNayak/git/commits/exp, I suggest you skip the top few commits. I agree on what Jeff's said, the name comes from the option in branch.c, also although your constraint is for branches we want to ,check tags in, the option can be extended for any refs, so that way merged also makes sense

Comment: @KarthikNayak Whatever happened to this?

Comment: @IanKemp It was merged upstream in September: https://github.com/git/git/commit/5242860f548d1869ac2779726ad496f0ae8ab5ca.  
That's git v2.7.0 I believe.

Comment: @KarthikNayak That would explain it - I was on git 2.6.2 on Windows and wasn't seeing the option. Just updated to 2.7.0 and it's there, `git tag --sort version:refname --merged` gives me exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @IanKemp Happy to help :D

Answer (score 17):

Use `git tag --sort='creatordate' --merged` to list all tags accessible/reachable from HEAD and sort them chronologically.

You can specify a ref if you don't want HEAD, like `git tag --sort='creatordate' --merged mybranch`

Comment: could you please tell how to pass the refname?

Comment: @RamkumarD You can just put it at the end, like `git tag --sort='creatordate' --merged mybranch`. The ref can be a tag, a branch, a commit hash, etc.

Comment: See also that answer to a similar/duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084124/1260896