# Git: find all tags, reachable from a commit

Tags: git, git-tag

How can I list **all tags**, reachable from a given commit?

For **all branches**, it is `git branch --all --merged <commit>`.
For **most recent tag**, it is `git describe`.

Man page `git-tag` suggests `git tag -l --contains <commit> *`, but this command does not show any of the tags which I know are reachable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all tags within a certain git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166548/how-to-list-all-tags-within-a-certain-git-branch)

Comment: `--contains` lists all tags for which the commit is reachable from the tag, not vice versa.

Comment: I would like to see an answer that works on windows, or preferably a platform independent variant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this script to print out all the tags that are in the given branch

```
git log --decorate=full --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=oneline HEAD | \
sed -r -e 's#^[^\(]*\(([^\)]*)\).*$#\1#' \
-e 's#,#\n#g' | \
grep 'tag:' | \
sed -r -e 's#[[:space:]]*tag:[[:space:]]*##'
```

The script is simply a 1 long line breaked down to fit in the post window.

Explanation:

```
git log 

// Print out the full ref name 
--decorate=full 

// Select all the commits that are referred by some branch or tag
// 
// Basically its the data you are looking for
//
--simplify-by-decoration

// print each commit as single line
--pretty=oneline

// start from the current commit
HEAD

// The rest of the script are unix command to print the results in a nice   
// way, extracting the tag from the output line generated by the 
// --decorate=full flag.
```

Comment: Great, this works! I still wonder why `git tag -l --contains` does not do what it is said to...

Comment: Cool. :-) glad to help

Answer (score 5):

Git now supports this natively, but (perhaps unsurprisingly) in a counter-intuitive way:

```
git tag --merged [revision]
```

The behavior (and the rationale for the name) [comes from](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=144034970528236&w=2) `git branch --merged`: you are asking to see all the items that have been "merged into" the specified revision. This phrasing makes sense for branches, but unfortunately less sense for tags.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41175150/1858225.

Answer (score 1):

> Man page git-tag suggests git tag -l --contains  *, but this command does not show any of the tags which I know are reachable.

`git tag --contains` is for the opposite search. It shows all tags containing the given commit. (This is the same behaviour as `git branch --contains`.)