# How can i get list of tags of a particular git branch?

Tags: git

I want to have list of tags of a particular branch.
Below are the branches i do have.

$ git branch

```
    master
```

- master_release

  new_branch

  new_branch_1

  new_branch_2

git tag command giving list of tags of all the branches.

I need the tag list of only master_release branch in format like

tag3

tag2

tag1

where tag3 is latest  branch

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be `git tag --list --merged`.

Docs [say](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#git-tag---mergedltcommitgt):

> `--merged [<commit>]`
>
> Only list tags whose commits are reachable from the specified commit (HEAD if not specified), incompatible with --no-merged.

---

There is also a more complicated way explained at [How to list all tags within a certain git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166548/how-to-list-all-tags-within-a-certain-git-branch)