# How to git reset --hard <tag> and remove all local unrelated tags?

Tags: git

Say I have cloned a repo and the tags are

- v1.0
- v2.0
- v3.0
- v4.0 (latest commit)

Now I do a

```
git reset --hard v2.0
```

Of course the latest commit is now v2.0 and the code is reset.
But when I give a `git tag`, I will still get

- v1.0
- v2.0
- v3.0
- v4.0

**How can I do a git reset to v2.0 so that the future tags v3.0 and v4.0 are also removed from local?**

What is the use case for this? - I have to calculate the current tag and previous tag.

Previous tag

```
echo $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags `git rev-list --tags --skip=0 --max-count=2` | cut -c2- | sed '2q;d')
```

Current tag

```
echo $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags `git rev-list --tags --skip=0 --max-count=2` | cut -c2- | sed '1q;d')
```

Comment: See VonC's answer for deleting tags. However, note that *all* references are *always* local, so all tags are also local. The `git describe` command never uses a descendant tag so there is no need to remove such tags. This leaves me quite puzzled as to why you asked this question at all.

Comment: @torek That's right. The current tag would be calculated fine as you said. But it also uses --tags to calculate previous version. I can delete the use case part in the question if it is deviating from the main question. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are running a nested `git rev-list --tags` *within* the `git describe`. That's a bit odd / unusual.

Answer (score 3):

[`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) will move HEAD, and has no bearing on existing tags.

You would need to delete tags with [`git tag -d`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#git-tag--d)

You can:

- list tags (git tag -l)
- [list tags contained by a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2383739/6309) (`git tag --merged <branch>`)

Any tag in the first list, but not in the second would need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use git reset --hard and among the commits to be canceled there are some that have the tag, they are not deleted. You can do this later by removing the tag. After removing the tag, all other related commits will be deleted.